# pthread passing object as argument to pthread_create

Tags: c++, pthreads, arguments

For the given program ::

```
void start(void *n){
  Node *obj = (Node *)n;
  cout << obj -> val;
}

int   
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i,n;
  cin >> n;
  Node *nodeObj;
  nodeObj = new Node[n];
  pthread_t *p = new pthread_t[n];
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    pthread_create(&p[i],NULL,start,(void *)(nodeObj[i]));   /*ERROR HERE in arg pass*/
  }                                                                               
  return 0;   
}
```

I get the following error::

> invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(void*)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’

I basically want to send each of the object `NodeObj[0]` , `NodeObj[1]` , `NodeObj[2]` ... to each of the new threads I create. the start function is where each of the threads start.

Comment: Use `nodeObj+i` instead of `nodeObj[i]`. And drop the cast-to-void* in the `pthread_create()` call; it will just work (though you might want to **join** those threads and cleanup that allocation when you're done).

Comment: Hi @WhozCraig thanks for the quick reply. I tried doing what you said, But I still get the following error: initializing argument 3 of ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’

Comment: The function should return a void*, not void.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will likely do what you want. I just threw it together so I apologize in advance if there are any syntax errors. It addresses your two issues (incorrect third and fourth parameters to `pthread_create()`) as well as uses RAII for allocation management:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int value;
};

void *start(void* p)
{
    Node* obj = (Node*)p;
    cout << obj->value;
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    if (n <= 0)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    std::vector<Node> nodes(n);
    std::vector<pthread_t> threads(n);
    for (int i=0;i<n;++i)
        pthread_create(threads.data()+i, NULL, &start, nodes.data()+i);

    std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(),
                  [](pthread_t& t) { pthread_join(t, NULL); });

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

**C++11 Threads : Their What's For Dinner**

I would advise using the C++11 threading classes and objects (thread, mutex, condition_variable, etc) over using raw-pthreads. They really are the bee's knees. Something similar (though with an auto-calculated N) appears below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node() : value() {}

    // member function we're using as thread proc
    void thread_proc(int n)
    {
        value = n;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // allocate nodes
    vector<Node> nodes(std::max(std::thread::hardware_concurrency()+1, 4U));

    // starts threads
    vector<thread> threads;
    for (int i=0; i<nodes.size(); ++i)
        threads.emplace_back(std::bind(&Node::thread_proc, nodes.data()+i, i+1));

    // wait for all threads to complete.
    for(auto &t : threads)
        t.join();

    // proof we really did hit *our* nodes in the threads.
    for (auto& node : nodes)
        cout << "Node value: " << node.value << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
Node value: 1
Node value: 2
Node value: 3
Node value: 4
Node value: 5
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is complaining about argument 3, the start_routine. The start routine (3rd argument to pthread_create) is specified this way: `void *(*start_routine)(void *)` a pointer to a method, that takes one void pointer (void *) as an argument and returns a void pointer (void *).

Your code is passing a start as the 3rd argument.

```
void start(void *n){
    ...
}
```

A mismatch to what the function is declared to take as the 3rd argument.

Changing your start to:

```
void *start(void *n) {
  return NULL;
}
```

Will make the error go away. 
The value returned from the method acts as the exit code of the thread, unless you are calling `pthread_exit`.

Answer (score 2):

The [linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) for pthread_create() contains a good example.

The thread_start function signature is

```
void * thread_start(void *arg)
```

In the main function you can see how to pass arguments (**&tinfo[tnum]**).

```
pthread_create(&tinfo[tnum].thread_id, &attr, &thread_start, &tinfo[tnum]);
```

Note that each thread recieves a distinct set of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of the thread function must be void *;

```
void* start(void *n)
{
//Code
}
```

Secondly, you must send the argument to the function this way:

```
pthread_create(&p[i],NULL,start,(void *)(&nodeObj[i]));
```

The requirement of argument passing is that the passed object must be a pointer to something. Even though nodeObj is a pointer, when you use array notation like nodeObj[i] you dereference it. Hence use the ampersand. &nodeObj[i];

You can also simply use `(nodeObj+i);`